# Why am I getting an 'import statement unnecessary'

Tags: vb.net

I am working in Visual Studio creating a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio. I am very new to the language, and am doing a very simple app. I currently have 3 different forms created on one project. I created a button that switches from the first form to the second form. I am not trying to create a button that switches from the second form to the third form, but cannot import the third form into the code of the second project without getting an unnecessary import error.

This is the code for the first form to the second form and this button works

```
Imports random__Fun_Page_2

Public Class frmMainPage
    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click


        Dim newForm = New frmChoiceOne()
        newForm.Show()
        Me.Visible = False

    End Sub
```

This is the code from the second form to the third form which gives me the error 'unnecessary import error'

```
Imports random__Fun_Page_3

Public Class frmChoiceOne
    Private Sub radioOneChoiceOne_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radioOneChoiceOne.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newForm2 = New frmChoiceTwo
        newForm2.show()
        Me.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

So my question is why can I import the second form on the first project, but cannot import the third form on the second project. Sorry if this does not give clear detail, but if there is any other information I can provide please let me know

Comment: Could we maybe get a a screen shot of your solution explorer?  Have you got these forms in separate projects withing the same solution maybe?

Comment: Are you sure it's an error and not merely a suggestion?  Usually "unnecessary imports" get a green squiggly underline which suggests that you could remove them, but that isn't something that prevents you from building.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, it may well be just a suggestion.

But then again, as a normal course of action one will VERY rare if at all need to use imports for the ability to reference say some other form? That "practice" of using imports for forms is really never required here. It not clear what example or why imports for form names are being used here?

So a general rule, imports are to allow with greater ease to reference or use some .net assembly or library code (by what we call a namespace). As an typical development approach, one does not need nor as a regular development approach do a imports of forms in applications.

So if we have say Form AA and we want to launch form B?

Your code can do this on the click event:

```
    BB.Show()
    Me.Hide()
```

Note that you can (and should) use .show() and .Hide() in palce of .visible.

Now in our form BB, to close the form and return? We could/would use this:

```
    AA.Show()
    Me.Close()
```

Notice how I CLOSED form BB. Note how I did NOT close form AA, since my whole application and startup form was form AA. (if I close form AA, then my whole application shuts down if that is the first "base" form you specify in the project to load on startup. So I did want to close form BB (not just hide it), and then return to form AA.

And in say form BB, there is nothing that prevents you from getting/grabbing controls or values from form AA (or say form CC or whatever).

So no need for "importing" the other

In form BB, you can get/grab/use controls from from AA like this:

```
Me.TextBox1.Text = AA.TextBox1.Text
```

So you have full use of any of the loaded forms as per above, and no imports of the forms is or should be required.

So, you would never "import say form AA or CC into that form BB. You have full use of any loaded form and its values etc. in code.

Perhaps you goal is some type of sub-form here? (we don't have that option in vb.net).

But the "general" idea and concept is to not use imports for use of other forms.

If you need some "general" code module for some subs to call (and code not really needed to be part of a form? Then under project, you can add a code module, and place the general subs and functions that are not part of say a form. But once again, no imports should be required to do this.

I will also point out in above, I did not create a "instance" of the form before I used it. Over time one can adopt creating a form instance, but in your general code you can just use the "one line"  BB.Show() and the form will load for you - not really a need to "create" the form instance before you use (show) it.